# Printing tuples on separate lines

Tags: python, tuples

I have a variable (x) which is made up of several tuples, each with three elements (name, location and mass). I want to make a list comprehension which returns the value for each element of each tuple in x on a separate line. The desired output is

```
Name: Tuple 1 name

Location: Tuple 1 location

Mass: Tuple 1 mass

...

Name: Tuple 2 name

Location: Tuple 2 location

Mass: Tuple 2 mass

...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to print your values?

Comment: What have you tried and what particular problem do you have? Show your code ([mre]). Also note, _I  want to make a list comprehension_ using list comprehension for side effects is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could generalize this using a list of prompts and zip to match them to the tuple entries. Format strings and the print separator can manage the line breaks:

```
tuples = [ ('Name1','Loc1','Mass1'), ('Name2','Loc2','Mass2'), 
           ('Name3','Loc3','Mass3')]

P = ('Name','Location','Mass') # prompts
print(*("".join(f"{p}: {v}\n" for p,v in zip(P,t)) for t in tuples),sep='\n')

Name: Name1
Location: Loc1
Mass: Mass1

Name: Name2
Location: Loc2
Mass: Mass2

Name: Name3
Location: Loc3
Mass: Mass3
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
x = (
    ("Name #1", "Location #1", "Mass #1"),
    ("Name #2", "Location #2", "Mass #2"),
    ("Name #3", "Location #3", "Mass #3")
)
print('\n...\n'.join([f"Name: Tuple {i+1} {x[i][0]}\nLocation: Tuple {x[i][1]}\nMass: Tuple {x[i][2]}" for i in range(len(x))]))
```

This will output:

```
Name: Tuple 1 Name #1
Location: Tuple Location #1
Mass: Tuple Mass #1
...
Name: Tuple 2 Name #2
Location: Tuple Location #2
Mass: Tuple Mass #2
...
Name: Tuple 3 Name #3
Location: Tuple Location #3
Mass: Tuple Mass #3
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the solution ;)